# Efficient way to check if elements of a list contain all elements of another list

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I have a list of strings named `strList` which contains around `800,000-2,200,000` elements. Each element contains around `100` characters. I have another list of strings called `findStrs` which usually contains less than `5` elements (5 to 10-character strings). I want to select the elements of `strList` that contain all of the elements in `findStrs`. How can I efficiently do that in Python? Here's how I am doing this but I wonder if there are more efficient solutions using list comprehensions for doing it:

```
finalStrList = []
for strr in strList:
    temp = []
    for findStr in findStrs:
        if findStr in strr:
            temp.append(findStr)
    if len(temp) == len(findStrs):
        finalStrList.append(str)
print(finalStrList)
```

I tried to devise a list comprehension-based method as well but, not surprisingly, it does not work:

```
[strr for strr in strList if [findStr in strr for findStr in findStrs]]
```

Comment: You could do `[s for s in strList if all([x in s for x in findStrs])]`

Comment: As an aside, you should try to stick to Python naming conventions, where camelCase is not used. Also, pick better variable names. I'm pretty sure this is a bug: `finalStrList.append(str)`

Comment: Wouldn't using sets be a decent solution here? Since number of elements doesn't matter, but instead existence?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Great solution! Could you post it as a solution then? :)

Comment: @chrisz I'm not sure if you could improve the solution using a `set` in this case.

Comment: @Amir can you post a small sample of your data?

Comment: @chrisz juanpa.arrivillaga's solution works. I cannot use `set` in my problem since every element is distinct already

Comment: Just curious, if all your elements are distinct, why would that prevent you from using `set`, and `issubset`?

Comment: @Amir That doesn't mean you can't use a set. You definitely _can_ use one; the problem is that it's not going to actually speed things up, because you still need to check each member of the set to see if your string is a substring.

Comment: @abarnert Ah, I misread the question.  Nevermind Amir

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I post your solution as answer for now. Feel free to post yours and I will delete mine :)

Comment: Changing to a list comprehension will almost certainly give you a small constant speedup, but your algorithm is still going to be `O(M*N*P)`—for each of your M strings, you have to check against each of your N find-strings by doing a full substring search against most of the P characters. If you want to speed things up more than that, you need to build a more complex data structure.

Comment: @abarnert Thanks for your suggestion. For my problem list comprehension serves good enough. My big list contains a couple of thousands of elements and the small list contains a less than 5 elements.

Comment: Is a speedup of, say, 25% (just a wild guess) really enough? Usually if things are slow enough that you need to optimize, you need to optimize a lot more than that.

Comment: @abarnert The big list usually contains around 20k-70k elements. Would that be considered very big?

Comment: @abarnert Each element has around 100 characters in it, more or less. Okay sure. I'll update the question now.

Comment: I'm still blanking on it… but maybe search on Computer Science SE. (If you find something that looks right, but you have no idea how to turn all that math and jargon into code, just post a link here.)

Comment: I thought of a couple ideas that might work to pull the factor of 80000 out into a separate term. The first one might take unacceptable space, and the second one might not actually work, but I’ll try them out when I get a chance.

Comment: @abarnert Actually I figured I was wrong about the number of elements of the large list. It turns out that I have about 800,000 to 2,300,000 of those! I guess this is considered a *very large* list of strings, isn't it?

Comment: One more question: Are the characters in the strings all pure ASCII, all Latin-1, or all BMP?

Comment: @abarnert In my case, they are all in ASCII.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [juanpa.arrivillaga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5014455/juanpa-arrivillaga) suggested in the comments section I can do what I want easily using the following list comprehension-based solution:

```
[s for s in strList if all([x in s for x in findStrs])]
```

Comment: It would be slightly faster if you avoid creating a list inside your nested list comprehension. So simply do `all(x in s for x in findStrs)`. This makes it exit fast if a single string is not found in the search string

Comment: @smac89 I'm doubtful that using a generator expression would be faster than the list comprehension, given the premise that "the small list contains a less than 5 elements" Because the short-circuiting behavior won't make up for the generator overhead. It would likely not hurt though, but for small use-cases, this overhead *can* be significant, so in my experience, it is always better to test this out empirically.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga The short-circuiting behavior should definitely makes up for the generator overhead unless we've got pathological inputs. We should be talking about a factor of around 2-4x for not short-circuiting, vs. something like 1.2x for generator overhead.

Comment: From a test on 100K strings, all other values equal to the OP, all random ASCII lowercase, according to `%timeit` on my laptop, the genexpr cuts the time from 189ms to 76ms.

Comment: Also: While `re` and PCRE1 slow things down, using PCRE2 knocks that 76ms down to 66ms, which surprised me a bit. (How much is there to JIT on a static 5-character pattern? Or is it because the PCRE2 beta wrapper is cheating and running Python compact ASCII strings as bytes—which happens to be right here, but not in general?)

Comment: Meanwhile, a min-Aho-Corasick that searches all 10 needles at once takes 147ms, which beats the OP's code and the code in this answer, but is slower than the genexpr version. Still pretty good for a pure-Python implementation, though. I tried hacking up Python's own stringlib into a multi-needle search, but the B-M delta function becomes non-trival and slows things down too much. Still need to sleep on my merged-trie and trie-with-dicts ideas. But so far, this version modified to short-circuit with a genexpr beats everything.

Answer (score 0):

If the match rate is not very high, we can reduce the time complexity.

```
finalStrList = []
for strr in strList:
    flag = True
    for findStr in findStrs:
        if findStr not in strr:
            flag = False
            break
    if flag:
        finalStrList.append(str)
print(finalStrList)
```

Comment: You don't need `flag`, just use `for`/`else`.